# Can I move or delete appverifUI.dll and vfcompat.dll from root, after Visual Studio installation?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code

I've recently installed Visual Studio and Visual Studio Code and the two .dll files are left in my `C:\` folder. Both are signed by Microsoft. Is there any reason for them being there? Can they be moved or deleted?

The files are:

- `C:\appverifUI.dll`
- `C:\vfcompat.dll`

Both Visual Studio and Visual Studio Code are the latest releases from the official site.

I assume they are left from the installation process and should have been moved/deleted by the installer, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found both DLLs after I added the C++ development tools to my Visual Studio installation. Before I only had the .NET desktop development environment set-up on this machine. The Microsoft documentation only states those DLLs are used to detect OS compatibility issues. I am running Windows 11 here and just deleted them using local administrator privileges without any obvious effect in Visual Studio C++ development set-up. So just give the deletion a try :) If Visual Studio is running on the system, it should not be a production environment anyhow.

Answer (score 9):

I've found these two files in the root directory of my system disk too. Just after installing WinSDK with Application Verifier checkbox enabled.

Searching for these filenames in registry shows that there are links to them.

Searching for these filenames in system disk shows that there are x64 versions of them in `Windows\System32` but no x86 versions in `Windows\SysWOW64` - the x86 versions are in the root of the drive.

I suggest (I did that) to move the two dll's to `Windows\SysWOW64` and edit the registry values to the corresponding new paths. Mine now is

- `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\UserData\S-1-5-18\Components\0AF818DE4685190F5347FAF54BD80C82\B5EBE9ABF3AC4B1284D69A0B704551A0`: REG_SZ `"C:\Windows\SysWOW64\appverifUI.dll"` and
- `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\UserData\S-1-5-18\Components\E0C37F311948CF28AE087B694A681271\B5EBE9ABF3AC4B1284D69A0B704551A0`: REG_SZ `"C:\Windows\SysWOW64\vfcompat.dll"`.

Do not delete them (who knows what it will lead to?), just move them to their x86 "colleagues" and edit registry.

Comment: It works for me. In my case C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ had older versions of the files. I've renamed them to *.bak, just in case and moved the ones in the root to C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ and updated the Registry as above. So far so good.

Comment: I just deleted them and rebooted successfully.